# jquery is changing variable on if else statement

Tags: jquery, css

Trying to change paragraphs color on .mouseover to red and .mouseleave to black. Meanwhile checking the title of the page. For example, if title for home page is"home", then I want the color to stay red, but if the user is on different page, then I want it to go black again. For some reason var = current_title is changing on each .mousover/.mouseleave function, therefore every paragraph stays red even after moving mouse away. 
Using console.log figured that variable changes after .mouseover/.mouseleave function, but cant figure out whats the problem. Any help?

jquery code:

$(document).ready(function(){

```
var Home = "Home"
var Store = "Store"
var Gallery = "Gallery"
var Shopping_Cart = "Shopping Cart"
var current_title = $(document).attr('title');
console.log(current_title);


$(".Home").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).css("cursor", "pointer");
    $(".Home_Text").css("color", "red");
});
$(".Home").mouseleave(function(){
    if (current_title = Home) {
    $(".Home_Text").css("color", "red");
}
    else {
    $(".Home_Text").css("color", "black");
    }
});

$(".Store").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).css("cursor", "pointer");
    $(".Store_Text").css("color", "red");
});
$(".Store").mouseleave(function(){
    if (current_title = Store) {
    $(".Store_Text").css("color", "red")
        console.log(current_title)
}
    else {
    $(".Store_Text").css("color", "black")
};
});
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="nav">
                <div class="Logo"><img src=""></div>
                <div class="Home"><div id="Home"><p class="Home_Text">Home</p></div></div>
                <div class="Store"><div id="Store"><p class="Store_Text">Store</p></div></div>
                <div class="Gallery"><div id="Gallery"><p class="Gallery_Text">Gallery</p></div></div>
                <div class="Shopping_Cart"><div id="Shopping_Cart"><p class="Shopping_Cart_Text">Cart</p></div></div>
            </div>
```

Comment: You are using '=' instead '==' in the if statements.

Comment: This solves it. Thanks.

Comment: Also your indentation is a mess. It's impossible to tell what is nested inside what with a quick visual scan. Clean and consistent indentation will help other people reading your code, and it will help you too.

Comment: I would recommend “===“ because you’re only checking strings. This avoids converting before comparing them.